# Java System.out.print backspace

Tags: java, printing, java.util.scanner

Okay, I am being driven a little crazy by this issue.

I am currently printing out multiple prompts to ask for a list of 10 numbers. I just use the `java.util.Scanner` as follows:

```
ArrayList<Integer> list_of_ints = new ArrayList<>();
Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
   System.out.print("Enter integer number "+(i+1)+": ");
   int input = reader.nextInt();
   list_of_ints.add(input);
}
```

Here's my problem: I don't want to have a crowded output where I get something like this:

```
Enter integer number 1: 10
Enter integer number 2: 2
Enter integer number 3: 9
etc...
```

Instead, I want to replace the line every time. I thought that I could simply use `System.out.print('\r          ')` but apparently it's not that simple. Whenever you enter an integer, you have to press enter, which then gives a next line, which means now suddenly instead of coming back to the start of the initial line, it goes to the start of the next line. Thus, nothing gets overwritten/deleted.
I have been searching for over an hour to find a way to go back to the previous line in Java, but have found nothing.

Does anyone have a solution to help me scratch this itch in my brain.
Thanks to anyone who has any suggestions.

I have tried to use `\r` multiple times, I have tried to use `\b`, I even tried some stuff like this which I found online:

```
System.out.print(String.format("\033[%dA",1)); // Move up
System.out.print("\033[2K"); // Erase line content
```

Nothing seems to work.

Comment: You need to use either a GUI or a 3rd party console.

Comment: Side note: `System.out.print(String.format(…));` is a weird construct as you can simply use `System.out.printf(…);` If the argument to the format operation is the constant `1`, you can just use `System.out.print("\033[1A");` But this is an ANSI control sequence which is not supported by all consoles. If you’re running on Windows, you may read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74321619/2711488). If you’re running inside an IDE (other than IntelliJ) you may have to enable ANSI interpretation in the settings.